# How to change from API to domain name in Flask-restplus API?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, swagger, flask-restplus

I am trying to forward my flask api to `mydomain.example` with the end point being `api.mydomain.example`

For example, my method `ping` would have a end point `api.mydomain.example/v1/server/ping`.
However, what I get is `xx.xxx.xxx.xx:5005/v1/server/ping` as endpoint.

Looking in other questions here in SO I found suggestions to modify `app.config['SERVER_NAME']` or to add `subdomain` to `route` decorator. But nothing works. (I get a 404 error when I do any of these modifications).

Here is a minimal working example:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app, version='1.0',
          title='My API',
          description='An API')

blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/v1')
api.init_app(blueprint)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
#app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'mydomain.example:5005'
#app.url_map.default_subdomain = "test"

server = api.namespace("server",
                   description='Server API')


@server.route("/ping") #, subdomain="test")
class Ping(Resource):
    def get(self):
        """
        Check if Server is still alive
        """
        return {"reply":"PONG"}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config["SWAGGER_UI_DOC_EXPANSION"] = "list"
    app.run(port=5005, host= '0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

I went to my domain admin page (`name.com`) and added url forward. 
In that case, `mydomain.info` goes to swagger admin page, but `mydomain.example/v1/server/ping` also goes to swagger admin page.

But still, I get xx.xxx.xxx.xx:5005 in the Request URL section.

How do I make it work with the subdomain name?

Comment: Are you pointing direct to flask or are you using a webserver like nginx or apache?

Comment: Do you have a server configuration for virtual hosts enabled? Did you created the A register for the `api` subdomain in your hosting provider? (which will allow you to get your dns trasnlation as you mean)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change your app configuration. What you need to do is to run your app on a WSGI server which will proxy your app (on port 80 for example) through web servers such as Apache and Nginx. The WSGI server needs an entry point to communicate with your app on the port you specified (5005 in your code snippet). [Here's](https://github.com/mking/flask-uwsgi) a fairly simple tutorial about that (for more details, you can also refer to [this](https://gist.github.com/bluekvirus/62691d0bed98f45fe153a600e127e37b) link).

Furthermore, API Gateways are your best friends here especially if you're publishing your APIs to the public internet. You can look at [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) or [Apigee](https://apigee.com/api-management/#/homepage) for API management with first-class support for Swagger (there are many others - including OSS).